# Formatting Date::Manip's Delta to days

Tags: perl, date

I have this routine,

I want to save that delta to count the days between all to and from days in the from-to pairs 
I have in the 2 dimensional array, I just need the workdays.

Say for

```
$date_from = 2012-02-09;
$date_to = 2012-02-13;
$delta_string = 4

sub calc_usage {
    use Date::Manip::Date;

    my $date_from;
    my $date_to;
    my $delta;

    my $i;
    for $i (0 .. $#DATE_HOLDER) {
        $date_from = new Date::Manip::Date;
        $date_to = new Date::Manip::Date;

        $date_from->parse($DATE_HOLDER[$i][0]);
        $date_to->parse($DATE_HOLDER[$i][1]);

        $delta = $date_from->calc($date_to, "business");

    }

}
```

Comment: It does but its not human readable the delta is Date::Manip::Delta=HASH(0xa0b9db0) (diff address on every run ofc)

Comment: That means it's a (reference to a) Date::Manip::Delta object. You could look for some documentation on that on http://metacpan.org

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To retrieve the delta values, you have to use the folllowing:

```
my @val = $delta->value();
```

wich gives an array of 7 elements where:

```
$val[0]   holds years
$val[1]   holds months
$val[2]   holds weeks
$val[3]   holds days
$val[4]   holds hours
$val[5]   holds minutes
$val[6]   holds seconds
```

you can also use it in scalar context:

```
my $val = $delta->value();
```

wich gives a string with the same 7 elements colon separated:

```
years:months:weeks:days:hours:minutes:seconds
```