# Mysterious perl undefined value with Date::Manip Objects

Tags: perl, date

I had this sub [Formatting Date::Manip's Delta to days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9193569/formatting-datemanips-delta-to-days) 
which worked perfectly after I used the help in the answer. Today I run my code again and I get `Can't call method "value" on an undefined value at` the line `@val = $delta->value();`

```
sub calc_usage {

    my $date_from;
    my $date_to;
    my $delta = new Date::Manip::Delta;
    my $period = 0;
    my $i;
    my @val;

    for $i (0 .. $#DATE_HOLDER_USAGE) {
        $date_from = new Date::Manip::Date;
        $date_to = new Date::Manip::Date;

        $date_from->parse($DATE_HOLDER_USAGE[$i][0]);
        $date_to->parse($DATE_HOLDER_USAGE[$i][1]);

        $delta = $date_from->calc($date_to, "business");
        @val = $delta->value();

        my @year_from = $date_from->value();
        my @year_to = $date_to->value();

        if ($date_to->is_business_day()) {
            $period += $val[3]+1;
        } else {
            $period += $val[3]
        }
    }

    $YEARLY_ALLOC_HTML = $period;
}
```

I have no idea why this started happening.

I call the function after the `@DATE_HOLDER_USAGE` is filled, and I have the imports

```
use Date::Manip::Date;
use Date::Manip::Delta;
use Date::Manip;
```

(probably not all of them necessary?)

Comment: Could you show us some values contained in `@DATE_HOLDER_USAGE`? Are all of them producing error?

Answer (score 0):

Schoolboy error, I had a new condition restraining the filling of the `@DATE_HOLDER_USAGE` 
Braking the code, effectively feeding non date elements to the date parser, getting out no values out of them.

In reply to M42's comment

```
my @dates;
$dates[0] = $DATE_FROM;
$dates[1] = $DATE_TO;
$DATE_HOLDER_USAGE[$inc] = [@dates];
$inc++;
```

.

```
2012-12-28  2013-01-02
2012-06-18  2012-06-29
2012-02-16  2012-02-21
```

but in some cases there wont be a $dates[0] and $dates[1] at all at some places in the holder just undefs I suppose.

Comment: Yes I made sure I get all the data in and replied to my answer, everything works